# Setting android:windowBackground from styles messes up app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I've got a problem with my application. I am trying to make an update for it so that the user can select his own theme for the app. However, that means I have to move the setting of background images from the .xml files to the `styles.xml` in my theme styles. I did this by removing `android:background="@drawable/bg"` from my xmls and added `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>` to my style. This looked to be OK in preview but once I ran it in the emulator, whenever I switched fragment, all the contents of the main fragment (loaded on startup) remained in the background at all times...
[image: The we, they, the zeros and all the buttons are from the first fragment but are still visible in this one for some reason...]

The we, they, the zeros and all the buttons are from the first fragment but are still visible in this one for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new theme in style.xml like below

```
<style name="AppTheme.Fragment" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_fragment</item>
</style>
```

Then on each fragment apply the theme as follow

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Fragment">

    <!-- your code here -->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now whenever you need to change the fragment background to a different one, modify the `android:background`option in the theme in `style.xml`

---

`@drawable/bg_fragment` is as below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because none of your fragments have any background. So when you are adding fragment the content will overlap on one another. Try setting background of the fragments OR you can use replace instead of add fragment.